Process KeyEvent inside Swift NavigationSplitView
I am trying to process the key events inside a NavigationSplitView in SwiftUI, but somehow the NavigationSplitView doesn't pass the events. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!!
This is the code that doesn't work as supposed to, and I'm not sure where to start looking for mistakes:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text:String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Text("Works:")
                TextField("test1", text: $text).onKeyPress(action: {
                    a in
                    print(a.debugDescription)
                    return .ignored
                })
            }
            NavigationSplitView {
                Text("a")
                } detail: {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Doesnt work")
                        TextField("test3", text: $text).onKeyPress(action: {
                            a in
                            print(a.debugDescription)
                            return .ignored
                        })
                    }
                }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


The code is supposed to print the pressed keys for both TextFields.

I didn't find a solution to the problem but a fix. Instead of using the ViewModifier, one could monitor the Events like this (doesn't work in iOS):
.onAppear {keyboardSubscribe()}

private func keyboardSubscribe() {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { (aEvent) -> NSEvent? in
        print(aEvent.keyCode)
        return aEvent
    }
}

